# How can I iterate different dataframe in a list of functions?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm a beginner in python and I'm losing my mind trying to find the best way to do the following task:

I have a large dataset in which every observation is referred to a different brand. On this dataset I have previously created some columns, useful to do some functions.

I've created some functions that create tables, then these tables will be included in an excel file. I have to do this for every dataframe, splitted for brand.

I have tried to construct a list of functions and a list of selected brands for which I need to create the file excel. But when I think to do this with a loop, I'm lost.

## functions that create tables that I need to insert in a file excel

```
def tab_new_born(df):
    tab_1 = df_cliente.astype(str).groupby('definitive_class').agg({'definitive_class': lambda x: x.count()})
    return tab_1

def tab_updated_and_working(df):
    tab_2 =  pd.crosstab((df_cliente.FIRMWARE_STATUS_UPDATE == 'updated'), (df_cliente.app_trans_features == 1), margins = True)
    tab_2.rename(index = {False : 'no', True : 'yes', 'All' : 'Total'}, 
             columns = {False : 'no_trans_in_7_last_days', True : 'yes_trans_in_7_last_days','All' : 'Total' }, inplace= True)
    return tab_2  

#file excel
output =  '_output.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')


tab_new_born(df).to_excel(writer, sheet_name= 'MHT_classification')
tab_updated_and_working(df).to_excel(writer,sheet_name = '#VM_operative')
tab_working_and_anomalous(df).to_excel(writer,sheet_name = '#VM_conn_problems_operative')
tab_working_and_registry(df).to_excel(writer,sheet_name = '#VM_registry_null')

workbook = writer.book

writer.save()
workbook.close()
```

I want to create a loop in which:
1) select the brand from the general dataset to obtain the single dataframe for brand;
2) for every separated dataset, execute the functions and create the respective file excel

Comment: how big is your df? does the whole df fit in memory?

Comment: My df has 20000 obs and 101 columns, but memory is not a problem. My problem is create nested loops to apply functions

Answer (score 0):

1. read the full df
2. get unique brands from full df ( see unique)
3. loop through brands
4. for each brand filter/select from the full df rows corresponding to current brand and create a sub_df
5. apply your functions on sub_df

Comment: if you try, I can help you fix it

Comment: select_brand = [1,28,97,110,60,40,90,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,80,41,100,42,96,62,63]
for r in select_brand:
    sub_df = df_MHT_communication[df_MHT_communication['M_BRAND'] == r]
            return sub_df.apply(lambda x: tab_new_born(x))